# LG K10 Rooting and Bootloader Unlock without a computer

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, lg

How I go about unloacking the bootloader on a LG K10 without a PC?  Can it be done or do I need a computer.   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need a PC to run the required fastboot commands. So, yes, it cannot be done without a PC.
One alternative can be to use another rooted Android phone with ADB and Fastboot binaries installed. Then connect the two phones using a USB OTG connector/cable and you should be able to use the fastboot commands.